# Why am I running into Stack Overflow Error

Tags: excel, vba

I've run into a Stack Overflow issue with the below code.  The error happened on `Set rngToCheck = Range("GenLoanAmount")` and I'm not really sure why since there doesn't seem to be enough happening that would cause that issue.  This code does work, so if deemed necessary by the community I will post it on Code Review.  Thank you for taking a look.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Set rngToCheck = Range("GenLoanAmount")


    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("FloodIns")) Is Nothing Then
        If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("FloodIns")) = "Y" Or Intersect(Target, Me.Range("FloodIns")) = "y" Then FloodEmail.Show
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("FloodInsAct")) Is Nothing Then
        If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("FloodInsAct")) = "Y" Or Intersect(Target, Me.Range("FloodInsAct")) = "y" Then FloodActEmail.Show
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngToCheck) Is Nothing Then
        If Intersect(Target, rngToCheck) Then
            rngToCheck.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("genCloseDate")) Is Nothing Then
        If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("genCloseDate")) <> vbNullString Then FundDateCalc
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: When you say the code does work, do you mean it only works when you don't get the error, or that it works whether or not you get the error?

Comment: Also, on which line is the error occurring?

Comment: Does this code, specifically `FundDateCalc`, trigger a change in the worksheet? To be safe, events should be disabled and then enabled at the end.

Comment: @Mistella,  I added the line of code that the debugger highlighted, and it works unless i get the error then Excel just crashes.

Comment: @BigBen The `FundDateCalc` does change a cell value in that specific worksheet.  Im not sure how to enable/disable events in the `Worksheet_Change` event, so I will do some research on that as well.

Comment: See the posted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This procedure handles the `Worksheet.Change` event, which Excel fires whenever a cell changes on that worksheet.

The handler changes cells on that sheet (or invokes code that makes changes on that sheet), and is therefore re-entrant. Disable events at the start of the procedure, and re-enable them before the end of it, to avoid recursing until the call stack can't take it anymore (i.e. until you get a "stack overflow" error).

```
Dim wasEnabled As Boolean
wasEnabled = Application.EnableEvents

Application.EnableEvents = False

'...code...

Application.EnableEvents = wasEnabled
```

Comment: Thank you!  Whats sad is that i have used `Application.EnableEvents` so many times before.

Comment: @ZackE on the bright side, you've contributed a "stack overflow" question to Stack Overflow, pretty legit if you ask me.